# Lists and lambda with 0

Tags: python, list

I am new in python. I want to give condition to 2 lists one of which might have zeros (x):

```
b=[64989000.0,44560000.0,36546000.0,36616000.0,32730000.0,30790000.0, 33820000.0,34528000.0,34206000.0,34163000.0,28811000.0]
x=[5650000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

d=list(map(lambda o,s:((o-s)/o)if s else 0,b,x))

def zdd():
    for a in x:
        if a == 0 :return x
        else: return d
```

when i run `zdd()` i get [-0.6035678889990089, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0] whereas i want if any number in lits x equals 0 then return 0 whereas if any valies from x more than 0 return formula in `d`

However it does not work. Could you please help me with this ?

The data is sourced from DB. If i run this code with manual data put here it works BUT when i use data for x and b form the DB i get 1 istead of 0. Why it happens ? how to fix it ?

Comment: It returns `[0.6, 0, 0, 0]`. Did you clear your file from extra code lines?

Comment: what do u mean ? i source data form DB  and sometime it turn 0 sometime it turns 1

Comment: I run your code as it is and get those values

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], making sure that the code that you post behaves as you claim.

Comment: that is the code i provided

Comment: With your updated b, x I get `[0.9130622105279355, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` for d and zdd().  Don't understand purpose of function zdd.

Comment: i know but when i source my MySQL database it does not perform the operation but instead turn [0.9130622105279355, 1 , 1 ,1 ,1 , 1 ,1 ,1 , 1 ,1 ].

Comment: by `return x` and `return d`, do you mean to return the whole list?

Comment: i mean return d (which if formula ). X is list from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works now. The problem was the memory was full and package not updating the code that is why no change was happening. So i restarted the system and it updated for changes.